# Till which latest version of IBM RAD we can integrate IBM ClearCase in IBM RAD?

Tags: integration, clearcase, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I have IBM RAD v9.6. I want to integrate IBM ClearCase with my RAD instance. Please let me know upto which version of RAD, we can integrate Clearcase with it.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From "[Integrating Rational Application Developer and Rational ClearCase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_8.5.1/com.ibm.javaee.doc/topics/rintegratingclearcase.html)":

> The support for Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter is deprecated.
>
> **It is only supported with the 32-bit installation of Rational Application Developer, version 8.5.5.x, or earlier**.
>
> In Rational ClearCase version v8, or later, Rational ClearTeam Explorer (CTE) Extension is the preferred Rational ClearCase integration with Rational Application Developer and Eclipse IDE.